# Why am I getting TypeError: readlinestest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'

Tags: python

Here's the code

```
def readlinestest(input):
    return len(input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argtest = ["", "/n /n", "/n /n /n"]

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
        results = list(e.map(readlinestest(), argtest))

    for x in results:
        print(x)
```

The expected output is something like

```
1
2
3
```

And the full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HW9.py", line 17, in <module>
    results = list(e.map(readlinestest(), input=argtest))
TypeError: readlinestest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'
```

From what I know about .map(), everything is correctly written. And yet: the error message. So something must be off.

Comment: If you call `readlinestest()` you need to provide one argument because it's defined as `def readlinestest(input):`. You don't provide one argument so you get the error.

Comment: If you want to use `map` you don't *call* the function but pass it as argument to `map`. Don't write `()` then.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That was precisely the issue. Thank you